Was Renne compatibility with Pater-Mater a result of the Gnosis Experiments?
in The Legend of Heroes: Trails in the Sky The 3rd we learned that before becoming one of Ouroboros's Enforcers, Renne was in a place called "Paradise" where she was molested where before attending clients she was giving a syrup
in The Legend of Heroes: Trails from Zero we learned that "Paradise" was one of many lodges ran by the D∴G Cult, one of which Tio was in where she was subjected to experiments using Gnosis which resulted in the amplification of her abilities. while Joachim said that "Paradise" operated separate from the other lodges, Renne was still listed in the book with Tio as those who were part of the experiments, implying that the syrup Renne was given was Gnosis
Before Renne joined Ouroboros, test subjects to pilot/control the Gordis-class archaism that Novartis was working on kept resulting in the death/coma/mental breakdown of the pilots with the project being frozen and subjecting being more carefully chosen with Renne being the first to pass all the tests
As Tio got enhanced abilities from the Gnosis Experiments that allows her to use her Aeon System to interface with machines (like when she is hacking or playing Pom Pom Party), was Renne's compatibility with the Gordis-class archaism Pater-Mater a result of Gnosis aswell?
